# How to fix issue when saving Excel file to users desktop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-permissions

Trying to save an excel file to users desktop from a c# asp.net web application. This worked fine on local machine when testing but not on remote server. Can someone help me fix this issue? Thanks!

Code:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath + @"\spreadsheet.xlsx");
excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: This code is executed on the server. You are trying to save a file on the 'desktop' of the server.

Comment: Agree with Steve, but also the path you have the error to is saving to C:\ directly, not the desktop

Comment: I think you both confused me more. So, should I save the file to a folder on the server example: c:\somefolder\ and then serve the file up to the user to save where ever?

Comment: You can only offer a download button to your user and let he/she decides where he/she wants to save the file.

Comment: You really have to keep in mind where your code is executing and what it's capable of doing. This code is running on the server. Have you ever visited a website and had it just put random files on your computer wherever it wants? No? Don't you think that would represent a big security vulnerability if sites could do that? How do you get files on your computer from a website? The website offers the file for downloading, and then the user chooses where to put the files. So you need to figure out how you offer files for download in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: How you go about doing that in ASP.NET depends on the type of application it is. Is this  Web Forms? MVC? Razor Pages? You should tag your question appropriately and give some context (you haven't explained what method your code is running in, just given us 3 random lines with no context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are perhaps using EPPplus (`excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);`). So if you use asp.net as your tag indicates you can send the Excel File to the browser and the user will get a Save File Dialog.

```
//convert the excel package to a byte array
byte[] bin = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

//clear the buffer stream
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

//set the correct contenttype
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

//set the correct length of the data being send
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());

//set the filename for the excel package
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"ExcelDemo.xlsx\"");

//send the byte array to the browser
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);

//cleanup
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```